# Powershell - Get-ADUSER - Getting response but dont want it

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In my AD, I'm trying to make sure everyone who is disabled (in description) is disabled (Enabled prop). 
So this report runs the query below and i'm getting a list.. I dont want a list. everyone who has "disabled" in the description is already disabled..

I only want a list if they have 'disabled' somewhere in the description but they are not disabled in the account settings.

`Get-ADUser -properties name,distinguishedname,description,enabled -Filter {(Description -like "*disabled*") -and (Enabled -eq 'True')} | select name,distinguishedname,description,enabled | Export-csv C:\temp\disabled.csv`

As you can see i'm still getting a list...
[image]

Comment: the default for `Export-SV` is to include the type info for the objects. [*grin*] to prevent that you need to add `-NoTypeInfomation` to your `Export`CSV` call.

Comment: No that isnt what i need. I need the list to return nothing if the conditions are all true

Comment: Does this work if you change `"disabled"` to `"*disabled*"`?

Comment: @Harry - ah! i misunderstood the reason you posed the image of your data. [*blush*] it is nearly unreadable for me. still, you will likely want to use that parameter to avoid the garbled CSV file that results. ///// last, PLEASE wrap you code in formatting markers. the instructions are linked on the page you used to create the Question.

Comment: I am not being clear. In AD, we have no enabled users with "disabled" in the description. I would like the list to be blank if that is true, but I am getting a list with all the values anyway.

Comment: To me, this condition should have no results at all.. and that's where I am lost... because i'm getting results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ADUser -properties name,distinguishedname,description,enabled -Filter {(Description -like "*disabled*") -and (Enabled -eq $True)} | select name,distinguishedname,description,enabled | Export-csv C:\temp\disabled.csv
```

I suspect that the test for whether it is enabled is looking for a string with a value of 'True' when in fact it is expecting a Boolean response of $True or $False.